# Angular Spring Boot: Redirection error: Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: java, spring, angular, spring-boot, cors

I'm using Angular 6 in the frontend and Java Spring Boot in the backend.

I want my login page to make request to server. Server redirects to dashboard page.

I have http://localhost:4200/login angular page which makes a POST request to server http://localhost:8080/login

The .ts file contains:

```
onLoginClickPost() {
  console.log('redirect request clicked');
  this.data.getUserInfoPost().subscribe(
    data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.userInfo = data;
    }
  );
}

getUserInfoPost() {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/login', {nextUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/dashboard'});
}
```

The server has @RestController with a method mapping to incoming POST request, which should redirect to http://localhost:4200/dashboard :

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> login_post(@RequestBody LoginReqPostParam payload) {

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

    try {
        headers.setLocation(new URI(payload.getNextUrl()));
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        logger.error("URI Exception: ", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.FOUND);
}
```

LoginReqPostParam is a simple class to have incoming JSON payload as object.

The login angular page is able to make POST request to the server. Now at the server, after returning the ResponseEntity from server, I'm getting following error in browser console:

> Failed to load http://localhost:4200/dashboard: **Request header field
>   Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in
>   preflight response.**

[image]

How do I redirect to http://localhost:4200/dashboard page? Do I need to add something to angular dashboard component files?

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response?

Comment: @sideshowbarker Request URL: localhost:4200/dashboard Request Method: OPTIONS Status Code: 200 OK Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:4200 Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Answer (score 0):

You are using `@CrossOrigin` for POST request but Angular (in development) is sending a *Preflight request* using OPTIONS.

I recommend you to use a development profile that permit all origins (you must create a custom filter in a Bean for these profile)

Answer (score -1):

Use Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: * extension for google chrome.
And enable cross origin resource sharing
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Comment: I'm using that extension, but still getting the error